# Angular page can't open

Tags: angular

I'm beginner to `Angular`  I'm try to make sample web site, I have some issue , I'm crated 2 pages , about.component.html and Contact.component.html

But I can't open those pages.

I want to know how to  correctly  set of link to that,  and what is best to 
use for the develop web site `Angular` or `Angular-js`?

**app-navbar.component.html**

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"     (click)="toggleCollapsed()">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
     <div id="navbarSupportedContent" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link"  >DASHBOARD<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.component.html">About</a>
          </li>
       </div>
    </nav>
```

---

**app-navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './app-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-navbar.component.css']
})
export class AppNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  date = new Date();
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import {IndexComponent} from './index/index.component';

    @NgModule({
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'inde',
        component: IndexComponent,
      },
      // map '/' to '/persons' as our default route
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/index',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
    ];
    export const appRouterModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Use [routerLink]="['/about']" or routerLink="/about" or [routerLink]="["someexpressionvariable"]"

Comment: @Gary Sir Thanks for  the guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `routerLink`. not `href`.

You can `routerLink`. after import `RouterModule`.

If you want to route to `about component`, you should write `route info` for `about component` in `app-routing.module.ts`.

Official document is here =>> https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

example code is (only required code)

**app-navbar.component.html**

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
```

**app-navbar.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({ imports: [RouterModule] })
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}];
```

Comment: Sir Thanks for your answer and guide , its work for me

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use **routerLink**  `<a routerLink="/about.component">`

and Make Sure that u  added that component in Routes`{ path: 'about.component', component: AboutComponent },`

Comment: Sir Thanks for your answer and guide